# Is the matrix norm of this matrix bounded?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, matrix-norms

Let $A$ be a nonsingular $n\times n$ matrix, $B= \begin{bmatrix} c_1&c_2&\dots&c_m\end{bmatrix}$ is an $n\times m$ matrix written in terms of its column and $v$ is a column vector of length $m$.

If $||ABv||<M$, does it imply that each vector $c_i$ has a vector norm at most $M$?

I solved that $ABv$ is a 'linear combination' of $Ac_i$'s but I don't know if that will help.

Comment: What is meant by $ABv$ has bounded vector norm? It is a well-defined vector, so its norm exists and is bounded. Secondly, the matrix norm of *any* matrix is bounded, i.e., exists.

Comment: @Chrystomath: Hi! I edited the question for that mistake.

Comment: Unless $n,m$ are ridiculously small ($1$) then it is not very likely that a single inequality $\|ABv\|<M$ leads to $m$ of them. Think of $B=I=A$ and $v$ very small.

Comment: This definitely isn't true. Pick any $B$ and any $v$. Let $0<M<\min_j\|c_j\|$ and let $A=\epsilon I$. When $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small, we have $\|ABv\|<M<\|c_j\|$ for every $j$.